# Get list of running nodes

Tags: ros, rosnode, rosgraph, rospy, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

is there a way to retrieve a list of all running nodes from within a node (`rospy` preferably)? I've already taken a look at `rosgraph.masterapi`. It seems appropriate but pretty complex. Is there an easier way than to dismantle the getSystemState call result?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164601/get-list-of-running-nodes/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
import rosnode
rosnode.get_node_names()
```

More detail in the [rosnode API reference](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rosnode/html/).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-14**:
Ah, missing the forest for the trees... Thanks, pal!

**Comment by [james P M](https://answers.ros.org/users/56428/james-p-m/) on 2021-10-12**:
anything for c++